# How to get IPv4 and IPv6 address of local machine?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am developing a windows application and I need to find the IPv4 and IPv6 address of local machine. OS can be XP or Windows 7.

I got a solution for getting MAC address like,

```
string GetMACAddress()
{
    var macAddr =
        (
            from nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
            where nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
            select nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()
        ).FirstOrDefault();

    return macAddr.ToString();
}
```

This is working in all OS.

What is the correct way to get IPv4 and IPv6 address that work on XP and WINDOWS 7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();;
IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;
Console.WriteLine(addr[addr.Length-1].ToString());
if (addr[0].AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(addr[0].ToString()); //ipv6
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information. But IPv6 returning ::1. Is there any way to get actual value?

Comment: @user970349, it should return something like fe80::9008:98d4:ffb8:25d8, is that what you mean ?

Comment: yes. its should return something like fe80::9008:98d4:ffb8:25d8. still returning ::1

Comment: thank you very much. It is working perfectly now after installing IPv6 correctly.

Comment: Don't forget, **"::1"** is the IPv6 equivalent of **"127.0.0.1"**.  There may be other addresses between **addr[0]** and **addr[addr.Length-1]** worth checking.

Answer (score 2):

To get all IP4 and IP6 address, here is my preferred solution. Note that it also filters the loopback IP addresses like 127.0.0.1 or ::1

```
public static IEnumerable<IPAddress> GetIpAddress()
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            return (from ip in host.AddressList where !IPAddress.IsLoopback(ip) select ip).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Note: This requires using the `System.Linq` and `System.Collections.Generic` namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my method for getting all the IPv4 addresses only.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets/Sets the IPAddress(s) of the computer which the client is running on.
    /// If this isn't set then all IPAddresses which could be enumerated will be sent as
    /// a comma separated list.  
    /// </summary>
    public string IPAddress
    {
        set
        {
            _IPAddress = value;
        }
        get
        {
            string retVal = _IPAddress;

            // If IPAddress isn't explicitly set then we enumerate all IP's on this machine.
            if (_IPAddress == null)
            {
                // TODO: Only return ipaddresses that are for Ethernet Adapters

                String strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
                IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
                IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

                List<string> validAddresses = new List<string>();

                // Loops through the addresses and creates a list of valid ones.
                for (int i = 0; i < addr.Length; i++)
                {
                    string currAddr = addr[i].ToString();
                    if( IsValidIP( currAddr ) ) {
                        validAddresses.Add( currAddr );
                    }
                }

                for(int i=0; i<validAddresses.Count; i++)
                {
                    retVal += validAddresses[i];
                    if (i < validAddresses.Count - 1)
                    {
                        retVal += ",";
                    }
                }

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(retVal))
                {
                    retVal = String.Empty;
                }

            }

            return retVal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: He wants both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

Comment: @Ramhound... yeah and that's clearly stated.  Could be easily modified to do IPv6.

Comment: This is the reason I downvoted your answer: **"Here's my method for getting all the IPv4 addresses only."** you don't indicate HOW to modify the code to get a IPv6 address.